# Gitbash version 2.9.0 cmd line slow

Tags: git, git-bash

My gitbash cmd line is taking about 10 seconds to execute a single cmd.

For example, `git --version`.
I just downloaded the latest version of git.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did the issue persist after my answer?

Comment: @vonC Hey i found out the issue. Turns out that my anti-virus trend micro is slowly it. i disabled it and all works fine!

Comment: Great! I have included the AV in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try and:

- unzip [PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.9.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit.7z.exe) (if you have a Windows 64 bits) anywhere you want.
  For instance: `C:\git\2.9.0`
- open a regular CMD console and set a PATH to:

  ```
  set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
  set PATH=%PATH%;C:\git\2.9.0\bin;C:\git\2.9.0\cmd;C:\git\2.9.0;C:\git\2.9.0\usr\bin
  ```

Then type `bash -l -i` and see if the issue persists.

The goal is to make sure you don't have any conflicts with other software in your PATH.

The OP found the issue in the comments:

> Turns out that my anti-virus trend micro is slowly it.
>   I disabled it and all works fine!

It remains to be tested if a simple exception rule (for instance on the git installation folder) would be enough for git to run normally (ie, if the AV is set to *not* check its git installation folder).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with TrendMicro on Windows (10)
and using the portable git solved my problem

I also tried to exclude the git path from scanning but that was not the solution and gits behaviour was still slow